# Postal cancels - city name unknown

Tags: translation, place-names

Two hardly visible postal cancels on a postcard from 1954. Can someone help me with this? (Zhejiang province perhaps?)[image: postal cancels]

Answer (score 2):

One the left, it is Zhejiang Province.  The county is Chun'an (淳安).

One the right, it is also Zhejiang Province. The county / town has no yet deducible. It is probably Wei (威) something.